# Making connection string reference instead of hard coding

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

Currently, my application has connection strings hard coded.

```
string connectionString2 = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
```

I'm trying to change it so I reference the connection string that is defined in the web.config file instead. I've tried a solution found on here below, however it's not working (data is not inserting into my table anymore). It compiles however.

ImportController.cs

```
string connectionString2 =    System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BillingUIEntities"].ConnectionString; 

using (SqlConnection _con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString2))
{
  _con2.Open();
```

Web.config

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

<add name="BillingUIEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model2.csdl|res://*/Models.Model2.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SWDB10DSQL;initial catalog=BillingUI;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

**Update:** I've determined that it is getting the connection string from Web.config, but it's including the meta data which linq/ my sql connection doesn't seem to want in the controller. I thought sub stringing could be a work around but I don't think that's a good way of doing it cause the meta data can change, resulting in a longer/shorter length string which would cause me to substring an invalid region of the connection string. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you using entity framework somewhere? Your connection string contains some metadata that is only relevant for entity framework. Where did you get that connection string?

Comment: I am using entity, see above. I got the connection string from the web config file, starting at data source

Comment: Another way of doing this without hard coding is to use .settings files. This gives you the advantage of changing them later on without recompiling the whole source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Seems like a nice solution, although I've been told I have to use the Web.config

Comment: Have you verified that that first line is actually getting the connection string? Why is the connection string in your web.config so different from the one in your first code snippet? Why are you using `SqlConnection` if you are using entity framework?

Comment: @frankhaverford well, I have no idea how exactly entityframework works but I have coded with .Settings files and their contents can be passed around so there shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Use ConfigurationManager instead of WebConfgurationManager.

```
string connectionString2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BillingUIEntities"].ConnectionString;
```

:) David